# How to remove Kotlin support from an Android project?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

How to remove kotlin support from a new project and work with only java support without creating a new project ?

Comment: Stop using Kotlin?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Step 1:** Delete or comment-out these lines from `build.gradle (Project)` file.

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.51' // My kotlin_version might be different from yours.
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
```

**Step 2:** Delete or comment-out these lines from `build.grale (Module)` file

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
```

**Step 3:** Then hit `Sync Now`.

**Note:** Whenever you navigate to kotlin classes, you will see a popup always display on their header and the code is still highlighted.

[image]

To remove this popup and do not highlight kotlin code, go to `File -> Settings` to disable Kotlin plugin.

[image]

Then hit on `Apply -> OK`, after that a dialog will display to notify you reset Android Studio, just hit reset. Next time you open the project, the popup is gone and kotlin code is not highlighted anymore. It just like a normal file in your project.

[image]

Comment: I followed those steps but i still see kotlin folder.

Answer (score 8):

You have to remove this lines from your build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

and

```
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
```

Comment: Don't forget the classpath in the project-level Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to select Java as Language over Kotlin as below:

Go to

**File->New->New Project->Select Any Activity Type(Ex: Basic Activity)**

Now you can select Language as Java instead of Kotlin as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Read the question. "Without creating a new project"

Answer (score -1):

While creating a new Project

> Select Java Language, instead of Kotlin

Comment: Read the question. "Without creating a new project"