# Remove kotlin from android studio project

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-studio

I'm new to android studio.
Delete kotlin from existing java project.

I just created a new java project in android studio and there is no kotlin dependency in gradle but still the output has kotlin library, How can I delete it?

Comment: Can you not just delete the Kotlin library and move on with your task?

Comment: An empty Kotlin project is about 3.29Mb and it's not cool you know

Comment: So the term `kotlin` is nowhere to be found in all Gradle files of the project?

Comment: @Robert it's not in app -> build.gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to File -> Settings to disable Kotlin plugin.
explained here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52231145/how-to-remove-kotlin-support-from-an-android-project#:~:text=To%20remove%20this%20popup%20and,code%20is%20not%20highlighted%20anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52231145/how-to-remove-kotlin-support-from-an-android-project#:%7E:text=To%20remove%20this%20popup%20and,code%20is%20not%20highlighted%20anymore).